# Creating a BitSet where the LSB bit is added as either 1 or 0

Tags: java, for-loop, bitset

I am trying to create a BitSet of 64 bits where I start by having 56 bits, which is separated into groups of 7. Then I check if there are odd number of 1s in each group. If so, then I want to add a 0 bit, else 1. This results in 64 bits totally

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i * 7; j++) {
        if (i < 3) {
            if (i == 2 && j < 6) {
                temp.set(j, r.nextBoolean());
            } else if (i < 2) {
                temp.set(j, r.nextBoolean());
            }
        }
    }
    if (temp.cardinality() % 2 != 0) {
        temp.set(7, false);
    } else {
        temp.set(7, true);
    }
}
```

Right now, it only gives me 7 or 8 bits

Comment: You don't want to add a 0. You don't understand how `BitSet` works. If you have a zero, you don't want to add it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code has several issues:

**Filling the `BitSet`**
The logic in your loop sets in the first iteration the bits at index 0 - 6 and in the second iteration at index 0 - 13. Thus the first group has 8 bits (at index 0 - 7) but the second group has only 6 bits (at index 8 to 13).

See it for yourself and watch the value of `j` over the iterations.

**Group cardinality**
`temp.cardinality() % 2 != 0` - `BitSet.cardinality`

> Returns the number of bits set to `true` in this `BitSet`

([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality())). Thus your evaluating the number of bits for the whole `BitSet` in each iteration. But you said you want to check the "number of 1s in each group".

**Setting LSB**
`temp.set(7, false);` and `temp.set(7, true);` - Setting the bit at index `7` (LSB) is only appropriate for the first group. But this code is part of the loop. You need to set the LSB of the current group.

**My suggestion**
I would recommend to split the task into two steps: Fisrt fill the `BitSet`, then compute the LSB of each group in the `BitSet`. The code to compute the LSB could look like:

```
protected static void computeLsbOf8BitGroups(BitSet temp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() / 8; i++) {
        int msb = i * 8;
        BitSet group = temp.get(msb, msb + 8);
        temp.set(msb + 7, group.cardinality() % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! If I want to randomize the first 20 bits (MSB) skipping the the pairty bits, which is either set at 1 or 0 depending on if the number of 1s are even or odd, should I initialize another BitSet ?

Comment: It depends. The `BitSet` you pass in to `computeLsbOf8BitGroups` will be modified. If you need the initial (random) state later on, then you have to make a copy of the random `BitSet`. If you don't need to keep the random state, then there is no need for another `BitSet`.